# How many months does it has to take to build a cruise.(grammar)

Tags: questions, subject-verb-agreement, subject-auxiliary-inversion

With reference to the title:

> How many months **does** **it has** to take to build a cruise.

Is my subject-verb agreement correct? Particularly **'does it has to'** or should I say **''does it have to''?** I really need to make sure about this *question word format.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only ever one tensed verb in a verb phrase (ignoring coordinations like "goes and eats"). If there is no auxiliary, then the main verb of the sentence is tensed. If there is an auxiliary, then the main verb takes a non-finite form: the past participle with *have* (for a perfect tense), the present or past participle with *be* (for a continuous or passive form respectively) and the base form (or 'infinitive') for all other auxiliaries.

So if there is a *do* (*does*, *did* and their negatives) introducing a main verb, the main verb is **always** in the base form, even if the main verb is a special one like *have to*.

**Edit**: so "does it have to" is grammatical, "does it has to" is not. (Thanks to Hellion for pointing out that I didn't actually say this in my answer).

Comment: (and therefore, "does it have to" is the correct option.)

Comment: Got it, excellent!. Thx both of you. Kidding aside, this is kinda funny coz Colin Fine has explained it in its most academic method, then Hellion has summarized it hehe.